# Combine throw new Error with await in one expression

Tags: javascript, postgresql, error-handling, async-await, try-catch

can I throw error and use await word in one statement using **AND** operator, the following code explains well my request :

`throw new Error() && await client.end()`.

This latter works fine till now, and for my question, is this the better form of writing this and will it create problems in some cases.

*My main purpose is to close the Data Base connection and throw the Error.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for such use cases I think the `finally` block is the right solution. See on [the mozilla docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch#the_finally-block). In your case it would be something like

```js
try {
    // stuff that can throw an error
} catch {
    // handle the error case
} finally {
    // in any case, close the connection
    await client.end()
}
```

Or, if you want to keep the connection open when there's no error, just move the close line in the `catch` block:

```js
try {
    // stuff that can throw an error
} catch {
    // handle the error case
    await client.end()
}
```